# Is there a tool for manipulating Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Using Azure, I would like to be able to extract an ARM template from a working configured Resource Group. I would then like to be able to reproduce the environment using a different Resource Group name. As far as I can tell. this does not work out of the box. Is there a tool that will clean up and parameterize the ARM template it can be used without so much work ? The purpose is to be able to make test and prod copies of our dev environments. Am I just trying to do this the wrong way ? Should I be using a specific tool ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no such tool, unfortunately. I suppose you are talking about the `Automation script` feature. It provides you with a baseline template, but it requires refinement (like you mentioned).

I'm afraid you'd have to clean it up manually.